# Cursor in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cursor, nstextview

I have a scroll view, and a number of custom views (same class) inside it. Each custom view contains an NSTextView. I want the cursor to stay as arrow all the time, because the text views are not editable. However, setting the cursor using attributed string only controls the areas where there are characters. So I tried to override the mouseMoved method of the scroll view. This does the trick but when I scroll the view by triggering the scrollWheel event, the cursor changed back to IBeam again.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just calling

```
[textView setSelectable:NO];
```

to force the arrow cursor to be used (assuming the textView is also not editable via `-setEditable:`)?

Otherwise, you might look into the following: [Managing Cursor-Update Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH8-SW1).

Comment: I know that will make the cursor arrowed, but I do want to the text to be selectable.. Thanks for the document reference, but I read it and still clueless. I guess NSTextView manages the cursor itself, as from the rendering of attributed strings.